# Create Multiple Consumer Group for same topic in Kafka -Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to create a multiple consumer or a group of consumer for same topic. As my requirement is to capture events from all application. If i deploy my project in 2 different VM , partitions get assigned to only one vm in which I deploy first and for 2nd it doesn't get assigned for the same topics.

Comment: Can u please clarify your question. It is not at all clear

Comment: I have a same groupid but even I try to consume from different vm's any one vm get kafka events & other doesn't.

Comment: How many partitions do u have on the topic?

Comment: Can u try to give a different group id and see if it consumes events?

Comment: I got 3 partition, I have tried wiith different groupid its working fine, but I want to keep same groupId

Comment: Can u post your project on GitHub? A minimal, verifiable sample.

Comment: you can find sample poc @ https://github.com/tejas07

Comment: Where is d code?

Comment: @Indraneel dude its just a POC as i said else you can create a simple Spring-Kafka run on 2 different ubuntu screen you will face my kinda problem.

Comment: I don’t see ur code in the github link u shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you want to receive all the messages from the topic in every VM. In this case you must specify different `group.id` in the properties of the consumer in each deployment of your application.

Comment: yes I have done that, but the issue is if I have 100  application every time I need to change the group id and deploy 100 times . So that is something in vain. Please contact me tejas.gowda@sugarboxnetworks.com

Comment: You can use some randomization, it depends on the technology, which you use (UUID, system time, etc). Also you can use some kind of unique parameters like the name of the server.

Comment: Even if I placed a counter How would I come to know that particular events received should be placed under new groupId. unnecessary I need to write a code & save a record in underlying db.

Comment: If you use a value that is sufficiently random (e.g. a UUID) then you don't have to worry about collisions and you therefore don't need to track which values have been used.

Answer (score 0):

Number of consumers in a consumer group must be equal or lower than number of partitions the topic has. If your topic has 1 partition and you created two consumers in same group then one of the comsumers will be idle(will not receive any messages). 
If partition number is not enough you can alter the topic to have more partitions.

Comment: Thxz,but my concern is not about the partition or balanced equation between partition & consumer group. My concern is how to create a Group of consumers to fetch msg from same groupId.